# Js not working in both frontend and backend in magento

Tags: magento

I really don't know what exactly has happened to my website suddenly. Js is not working on both frontend and backend too. It is showing me so many errors which is due to js. I searched it on net and found some answers that are delete js folder and then upload it again or make the js folder and index.php folder to 644 or 755 or 777. I tried all the thing but nothing has been worked for me. Any help would be appreciated.

[Website url](http://kiranprakashan.com/kicxonline2/)

My magento version is 1.6.0

Frontend Errors:-

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).tabs is not a function


if ($(el.parentNode).hasClassName('active')) {

/kicxonline2/ (line 186)
TypeError: elementClassName is undefined


return (elementClassName.length > 0 && (elementClassName == className ||

3
prototype.js (line 2304)
TypeError: $(...).hasClassName is not a function


if ($(el.parentNode).hasClassName('active')) {

/kicxonline2/ (line 186)
ReferenceError: __verti is not defined
4
svc?m=...rti.run (line 1)
ReferenceError: __verti is not defined


return (elementClassName.length > 0 && (elementClassName == className ||

prototype.js (line 2304)
TypeError: elementClassName is undefined


return (elementClassName.length > 0 && (elementClassName == className ||

5
prototype.js (line 2304)
ReferenceError: __verti is not defined
```

Comment: Any JS error? please post it here.

Comment: I think you need to add jQuery.noConflict() after your jquery library load.
and use jQuery instead of $ sign.

Comment: make sure that jQuery lib is included (you can check by viewing page source and then see jQuery lib and then go to that particular link) and then use jQuery.noConflict()  for your custom jquery functions and library.

Comment: In my localhost, everything has been working fine. I also didnot installed any extension. I really don't know what actually has encountered in my site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My actually problem was that when i looked my website using firebug then i came into conclusion that rest of my js are working except prototype js folder. I changed it's permission from 744 to 644. Kudosh it worked and my website has started working again normally. So, by chance in future if any one of the magento users are facing the same problem then just check all of your js is working or not through firebug. If it is showing that you are not having a permisison on any scripts or folder then try to change the permission to 644.
Hope, it will helps you. In my other project case, i had changed js/index.php to 755 and prototype folder and it's sub directories to 755.

Comment: turning prototype folder permissions to 644 worked for me. Wasted 4 hrs today on this.. finally it worked. Thanks..

Answer (score 4):

you need to disable your module one bye one.

the problem is jQuery conflict.

Hope it helps.

Thanks,